# How to show a snapshot of an article from another webpage?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web

I've developed a website for my rugby club. We currently have one page with news articles on it (each with there own unique id's per story).

What I'd like to do is have a separate page for each story, then show a snap-shot of that story (say headline and first paragraph) on a Headlines page.

How could I do this? Via javascript or php? (forgive a neewbie)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `headline` field and a `text` field in your `Article` table.

To extract the first paragraph of the text, use the [explode](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.explode.php) function.

```
$paragraph = explode("\n", $text);

echo $paragraph[0];
```

If your text contains `<p></p>` :

```
$paragraph = explode("</p>", $text);

echo $paragraph[0];
```

Comment: Thanks @GG. So essentially this would break down the article into an array and then I'd simply state which numbers of the array I want to display?

How do I tell the function which paragraph to pick up (remembering that the paragraph is on another page)?

Comment: Get the paragraph in your database once for the Headlines page and a second time for the Article page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Links With URL Preview](http://cssglobe.com/lab/tooltip/03/) from [Easiest Tooltip and Image Preview Using jQuery](http://cssglobe.com/easiest-tooltip-and-image-preview-using-jquery/).

See the Example 3:

#### Example 3: Links With URL Preview

> This demands a bit more effort but it might be worth it as an extra feature to add to your sites. What you’ll need here is a small size screenshot of the target url. You’ll put screenshot image location in in REL attribute of the A tag and script will do the rest.

Comment: That looks a great tool, and something I'll ferret away for later use, but not really what I'm after to be honest

Comment: What you wanna do then? If you can explain clearly, perhaps I would be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use [jQuery's load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/) feature to grab the article page, and trim out stuff you don't need. I wouldn't necessarily recommend this though as the loaded file counts as a page visit, and could screw up your analytics.

Are you using a CMS? This is a fairly standard feature of systems such as Wordpress, Joomla, Perch, etc.

Comment: I did think about this, but I'm concerned that if someone has scripts turned off, the jQuery won't work.

And no, I'm not using any sort of CMS